# Is it possible to get the length of an array using a function?

Tags: c, arrays, sizeof

As far as I know, the following code can be used to obtain the length (meaning how many items it contains) of an array (in this example, an integer array):

```
int arrayOfInt[] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };

int lenght = sizeof(arrayOfInt) / sizeof(int);
```

This gives "5" as output, which is correct.
However, if i use the same code in a function, it does not work.

```
int getLenght(int intArray[])
{
    return sizeof(intArray) / sizeof(int);
}

lenght = getLenght(arrayOfInt);
```

Using the function above, i get "1" as output. Which is not correct. Why does this happen? Am i doing something wrong or is it not possible?

Comment: Just saying, are you using `lenght` as _typo_?

Comment: No, what you want is not possible. See also [C FAQ on arrays and pointers](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html).

Comment: *"Using the function above, i get "1" as output. Which is not correct."* -- can you, by visual inspection, tell the length of `int intArray[]`?

Comment: What happens to `intArray` when it is passed as a parameter to a function? (hint: It is converted to a pointer.) What is `sizeof (a pointer)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible. Arrays, when passed as function argument, decays to the pointer to the first element, so essentially, inside the function,all you have is a pointer to the first element of the array.

Moreover, `sizeof` operator works on the supplied variable *type*, it has no way of knowing the actual type *before* the transformation.

To elaborate,

```
 int getLenght(int intArray[])
```

and

```
 int getLenght(int *intArray)
```

are functionally and behaviorally same. It's not an *array* anymore.

---

Having said that, just a suggestion, a more robust way of getting the number of elements in an array would be

```
  int length = sizeof(arrayOfInt) / sizeof(arrayOfInt[0]);
```

This makes the expression independent of the hardcoded datatype, retaining the actual purpose.